# Running two different ES on a same machine and configuring kibana accordingly

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-6, kibana-6

I have installed two ES on my machine. One is 5 version(localhost:9200) and the other is 6 version(localhost:9500). Version 5 is used to index and store data alone while Version 6 is used to do some analytics using kibana dashboards.When i start kibana, the kibana automatically stops stating that all the ES should be on the same version. Is there any way, i can stop kibana from reading localhost:9200 ?

Comment: did you configured the kibana in the kibana.yml file? which es is been configured?

Comment: is it something like #The URL of the Elasticsearch instance to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti yes,I have already changed it as - elasticsearch.hosts:["localhost"9500"] . Please let me know if i have to change something more. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

like @Abhijit Bashetti stated in the comment, you need to modify kibana.yml file in order to point kibana to the elasticsearch instance you wish.

you should change "localhost:9200" to "localhost:9500" in order for kibana to reach the ES v6.

Comment: I have already changed it as -  elasticsearch.hosts:["http://localhost"9500"] . Please let me know if i have to change something more. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: do you have also two kibana instances running? you need to make sure you are using the kibana v6 to access ES v6

Comment: i am using only one kibana which is 6 version.But i have 2 elasticsearch ,one is 5 and the other is 6.

Comment: so kibana6 is using the default of localhost:9200 and reaches ES5. you need to change elasticsearch.hosts:["localhost"9500"]  ---> elasticsearch.hosts:"localhost:9500"

Comment: ES5 is running on 9200 and ES6 is running on 9500.I have configured kibana.yml to 9500 as i have mentioned in my above post.kibana starts and it ends abruptly stating that all versions of ES should be 6 it seems.

Comment: From the snippet you pasted it looks like there's a bad syntax,: and that might be the issue. It should be: "localhost:9500' and not "localhost"9500"

Comment: i will check on this.Thanks ziv.